# Error: formControlName must be used with a parent formGroup directive. You'll want to add a formGroup directive - Angular reactive forms

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have the following template. I'm trying to get to grips with reactive forms but am having a problem.

```html
<form [formGroup]="guestForm" novalidate>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <form>
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                <div class="form-group col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                    <label>First Name*  </label>
                    <input formControlName="firstname" type="text" class="form-control input-sm">
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</form>
```

Then in my component I have:

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'guest-input',
    templateUrl: './guest-input.component.html',
})
export class GuestInputComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input()
    guest: Guest;

    guestForm: FormGroup;
    
    constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.guestForm = this._fb.group({
            firstname: ['test', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]]
        });
    }
}
```

This all looks fine to me but for some reason I am getting:

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: formControlName must be used with a parent formGroup directive.  You'll want to add a formGroup
> directive and pass it an existing FormGroup instance (you can create one in your class).

I thought I had declared this in my `<form>`.

Comment: In my case I accidently placed a formcontrol outside form tag

Answer (score 96, accepted):

You have nested form tag inside form tag with `FormGroup` directive, remove it:

```html
<form [formGroup]="guestForm" novalidate>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <form> -> Remove this
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                <div class="form-group col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                    <label>First Name*  </label>
                    <input formControlName="firstname" type="text" class="form-control input-sm">
                </div>
            </div>
        </form> -> Remove this
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I have the same problem with him but I didn't duplicate my form  tag. The error that shows look exactly like him

Comment: Check if you have an input somewhere with a `formControlName` attribute but not inside a `form` tag. Then remove it

Answer (score 13):

In `modelDrivenForms`, `[formGroup]="guestForm"` should be in the parent element

```
<div class="form-group col-md-3 col-sm-6" [formGroup]="guestForm">
  <label>First Name*  </label>
  <input formControlName="firstname" type="text" class="form-control input-sm">
</div>
```

Comment: This is the one that worked for me.  I had the formGroup nested to deep.

Answer (score 5):

Those error are so not descriptive...
In my case - it turned up that I have doubled `formControlName='...'` inside my child component.

Parent component:

```
<div [formGroup]="formGroup">
    <quill-text-editor formControlName="my_control"></quill-text-editor>
</div>
```

quill-text-editor component template:

```
<quill-editor
  formControlName="my_control"//<--- I've deleted this to fix the error.
  (onFocus)="onEditorFocus()"
  (onBlur)="onEditorBlur()"
></quill-editor>
<hr>
<div class="toolbar">
  <div class="tool">...
```

Answer (score 3):

When you take form-control without formGroup.

Error code:

```
<ul class="list-unstyled noti-list m-0">
<li class="d-flex align-items-center">

  <div class="custom-switch ml-auto">
    <input
      formControlName="promotionMaterial"
      (change)="onChange($event)"
      class="tgl tgl-light tgl-primary"
      id="promotionMaterial"
      type="checkbox"
    />
    <label class="tgl-btn m-0" for="promotionMaterial"></label>
  </div>
</li>
<li class="d-flex align-items-center">

  <div class="custom-switch ml-auto">
    <input formControlName="offer" (change)="onChange($event)" class="tgl tgl-light tgl-primary" id="offer" type="checkbox" />
    <label class="tgl-btn m-0" for="offer"></label>
  </div>
</li>
<li class="d-flex align-items-center">
  <div class="custom-switch ml-auto">
    <input
      formControlName="termsAndConditions"
      (change)="onChange($event)"
      class="tgl tgl-light tgl-primary"
      id="termsAndConditions"
      type="checkbox"
    />
    <label class="tgl-btn m-0" for="termsAndConditions"></label>
  </div>
</li>
```

**In [Error code] I take "formControlName" so it does not work for me.**

Solution:

```
<ul class="list-unstyled noti-list m-0">
<li class="d-flex align-items-center">

  <div class="custom-switch ml-auto">
    <input
      [formControl]="promotionMaterial"
      class="tgl tgl-light tgl-primary"
      id="promotionMaterial"
      type="checkbox"
    />
    <label class="tgl-btn m-0" for="promotionMaterial"></label>
  </div>
</li>
<li class="d-flex align-items-center">

  <div class="custom-switch ml-auto">
    <input [formControl]="offer class="tgl tgl-light tgl-primary" id="offer" type="checkbox" />
    <label class="tgl-btn m-0" for="offer"></label>
  </div>
</li>
<li class="d-flex align-items-center">
  <div class="custom-switch ml-auto">
    <input
      [formControl]="termsAndConditions"
      class="tgl tgl-light tgl-primary"
      id="termsAndConditions"
      type="checkbox"
    />
    <label class="tgl-btn m-0" for="termsAndConditions"></label>
  </div>
</li>
```

**In solution i take [formControl] insted of formControlName its working fine**

Answer (score 1):

so the question is that if you have just one form control do you even need a formgroup?

In my case, I have to pass my input value to the parent component with #ControlValueAccessor through registerOnChange method.

when I set a formControl inside a formGroup everything is sunshine and roses, otherwise I catch the same error.

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
    <mat-label > label</mat-label>
    <input matInput formControlName="planValue">
</mat-form-field>
```

in comparison with:

```
<form [formGroup]="valueFG" >

<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
    <mat-label > label</mat-label>
    <input matInput formControlName="planValue">       
</mat-form-field></form>
```

Comment: Yes! This! Bard will tell you that a FormGroup is not required and that you can use a `formcontrol` outside of a form. Is it incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="col-md-12" formArrayName="educations">
</div>
```

ts file code

```
educations: this.formBuilder.array([]),
```

Or

```
<form [formGroup]="manageOrderForm">

</form>
```

ts file code
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-order',
  templateUrl: './order.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./order.component.css']
})
export class OrderComponent implements OnInit {

  manageOrderForm: any;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**
The code [formGroup]="guestForm" must go a couple of levels above, example:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-3 col-sm-6" [formGroup]="guestForm">
  <div>
    <div>
      <label>First Name* </label>
      <input formControlName="firstname" type="text" class="form-control input-sm">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In My case my form was closed before it should have been:

```
  <div>
  <mat-card>
    <mat-card-header>
  <mat-card-title>{{ actionName }} Categoria</mat-card-title>

    </mat-card-header>
    <mat-card-content>
      <form [formGroup]="categoryForm" #categoryFormDirective="ngForm"></form>

      <mat-form-field class="w-300">
        <mat-label>Nome</mat-label>
        <input matInput type="text" formControlName="name" />
      </mat-form-field>
    </mat-card-content>
    <mat-card-actions>
      <button mat-raised-button color="warn" (click)="cancel()">
        Cancelar
      </button>
      <button mat-raised-button color="warn" (click)="save()">Salvar</button>
    </mat-card-actions>
  </mat-card>
</div>
```

It started working after changing to the code below:

```
<div>
  <mat-card>
    <mat-card-header>
      <mat-card-title>{{ actionName }} Categoria</mat-card-title>
    </mat-card-header>
    <mat-card-content>
      <form [formGroup]="categoryForm" #categoryFormDirective="ngForm">
        <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column">
          <mat-form-field class="w-300">
            <mat-label>Nome</mat-label>
            <input matInput type="text" formControlName="name" />
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>
      </form> //<--Closing form Here
    </mat-card-content>
    <mat-card-actions>
      <button mat-raised-button color="warn" (click)="cancel()">
        Cancelar
      </button>
      <button mat-raised-button color="warn" (click)="save()">Salvar</button>
    </mat-card-actions>
  </mat-card>
</div>
```