# Why FormArrayGroup is throwing an error when it is used with nested form group in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a form group like the following:

```
this.addressInfoForm = new FormGroup({
      addressLine1: new FormControl("", [Validators.required]),
      addressLine2: new FormControl("", []),
      city: new FormControl("", [Validators.required]),
      province: new FormControl("", []),
      postalCode: new FormControl("", [Validators.required]),
      country: new FormControl({ value: "", disabled: true }, [
        Validators.required
      ]),
      stuff: new FormGroup({
        x1: new FormControl("x1"),
        x2: new FormControl("x2")
      }),
      email: new FormControl("", [Validators.email]),
      phones: this.fb.array([
        this.fb.group({
          phoneNumber: "",
          phoneType: ""
        })
      ])
    });
```

I don't know why my formArrayGroup is not rendering the phones and throwing the error

```
ERROR
Error: formControlName must be used with a parent formGroup directive. You'll want to add a formGroup
directive and pass it an existing FormGroup instance (you can create one in your class).
```

Here is my html

```
<hello class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center mt-4" name="{{ name }}"></hello>

<div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center mt-4">
  <form [formGroup]="addressInfoForm">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Address 1</label>
      <input
        type="email"
        class="form-control"
        id="exampleFormControlInput1"
        placeholder="Please Enter Address 1"
        formControlName="addressLine1"
      />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleFormControlInput2">Address 2</label>
      <input
        type="email"
        class="form-control"
        id="exampleFormControlInput2"
        placeholder="Please Enter Address 2"
        formControlName="addressLine2"
      />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleFormControlInput3">city</label>
      <input
        type="email"
        class="form-control"
        id="exampleFormControlInput3"
        placeholder="Please Enter City"
        formControlName="city"
      />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleFormControlInput4">Province</label>
      <input
        type="email"
        class="form-control"
        id="exampleFormControlInput4"
        placeholder="Please Enter Province"
        formControlName="province"
      />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleFormControlInput5">Postal Code</label>
      <input
        type="email"
        class="form-control"
        id="exampleFormControlInput5"
        placeholder="Please Enter Postal Code"
        formControlName="postalCode"
      />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleFormControlInput6">Country</label>
      <input
        type="email"
        class="form-control"
        id="exampleFormControlInput6"
        placeholder="Please Enter Country"
        formControlName="country"
      />
    </div>

    <div class="mt-4" formGroupName="stuff">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleFormControlInput6">X1</label>
        <input
        type="text"
        class="form-control"
        formControlName="x1"
      />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleFormControlInput6">X2</label>
        <input
        type="text"
        class="form-control"
        formControlName="x2"
      />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleFormControlInput7">Email</label>
      <input
        type="email"
        class="form-control"
        id="exampleFormControlInput7"
        placeholder="name@example.com"
        formControlName="email"
      />
    </div>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mt-1" (click)="AddPhone()">
      Add Phone
    </button>
    <div class="mt-4" formArrayName="phones">
      <div *ngFor="let phone of phones.controls; let i=index; let j=index">
        <form [formGroupName]="i">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="phone{{i + 1}}">Phone No {{i + 1}}</label>
            <input
          type="email"
          class="form-control"
          id="phone{{i + 1}}"
          formControlName="phoneNumber"
          placeholder="name@example.com"
        />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="phonetype{{i + 1}}">Phone Type {{i + 1}}</label>
            <input
          type="email"
          class="form-control"
          id="phonetype{{i + 1}}"
          formControlName="phoneType"
          placeholder="name@example.com"
        />
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

I created an example on stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kzntcc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

If you deleted the html part of the FormArray, the app will work.. if you deleted the html part of the nested group, the app would work.. it almost made me think that a nested form group and form array can't be used together!?

As you can see, it detects that there are 2 phones in my array and the form builder is rendering this as expected.. for some reason I can't figure this out!!

Comment: Already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43306002/904375
Remove the `<form>` tag you have used for `phones` and move the `[formGroupName]` to the same element as the `*ngFor`.

Comment: @ZeeshanSiddiqui I already looked at this thread.. this is not my problem.. please refer to my stackblitz to see a full example.. like I mentioned in the question.. if you deleted the nested form group and left the form array it will just work fine..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Remove the "form" in the formArray
2. remove the let j=index in the *ngFor
3. put the [formGroupName]="i" in the div of *ngFor

```html
    <div class="mt-4" formArrayName="phones">
          <div *ngFor="let phone of phones.controls; let i=index;" [formGroupName]="i">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="phone{{i + 1}}">Phone No {{i + 1}}</label>
                <input
              type="email"
              class="form-control"
              id="phone{{i + 1}}"
              formControlName="phoneNumber"
              placeholder="name@example.com"
            />
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="phonetype{{i + 1}}">Phone Type {{i + 1}}</label>
                <input
              type="email"
              class="form-control"
              id="phonetype{{i + 1}}"
              formControlName="phoneType"
              placeholder="name@example.com"
            />
              </div>
          </div>
```

[Your forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ajhok2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Thank you Eliseo.. Your solution works but I am still struggling to understand why removing the form tag fixed the issue.. I had a form tag in the form array group before and it did not error. It started erroring when I added the stuff object as a nested form group